# How do I determine the length of a column equal to a certain value in r?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find how many data points are present for each of my categorical variables in the column genotype. So far the following code returns the same values when the first line should return a value roughly 1/3 of the lower line of code.

```
length(CYP$Genotype == "CYP1B1 KO")
length(CYP$Genotype)
```

Comment: `sum` not `length` as the comparison returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` the same length as the original vector.

Comment: Try `sum(CYP$Genotype == "CYP1B1 KO")` to get the number for a particular genotype or `table(CYP$Genotype)` to get the frequency of each genotype. When you apply `sum()` to a logical vector, TRUE becomes 1 and FALSE becomes 0.

Comment: Try ‘table( CYP$Genotype)’

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you want to use `sum` instead of `length` to get the frequency of a variable. If you use `length` on the condition, then it will return the number of items in the vector, which is 8 in this case.

```
CYP$Genotype == "CYP1B1 KO"
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

length(CYP$Genotype == "CYP1B1 KO")
# [1] 8
```

Instead, if you use `sum`, then it will count the number of `TRUE` statements (which are counted as 1s, whereas, `FALSE` is a 0).

```
sum(CYP$Genotype == "CYP1B1 KO")
# [1] 4
```

As mentioned by @dcarlson, you can use `table` to get the frequency of the different values in the column, which you could put back into a dataframe.

```
data.frame(n = cbind(table(CYP$Genotype)))
#          n
#CYP1B1 KO 4
#GRB3C2 F2 1
#RGB2B1 G1 3
```

Or you can use `count` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

CYP %>% 
  count(Genotype)

#   Genotype n
#1 CYP1B1 KO 4
#2 GRB3C2 F2 1
#3 RGB2B1 G1 3
```

**Data**

```
CYP <- structure(list(Genotype = c("CYP1B1 KO", "CYP1B1 KO", "CYP1B1 KO", 
"CYP1B1 KO", "RGB2B1 G1", "RGB2B1 G1", "RGB2B1 G1", "GRB3C2 F2"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```